# Non-random movements

Tags: statistics, algorithmic-randomness

I know that the hedge fund Renaissance Technologies use computer-based models to predict price changes in financial instruments. These models are bases on analyzing as much data as can be gathered, then looking for non-random movements to make predictions. Could anyone have time to tell me how is it possible to find 'non-random movements'? I know it is essentially statistics and probably a bit of probability. What theory do I have to look for? Any examples maybe?

I doubt that the randomness of the stock markets can be overcome entirely by any kind of modeling, but with lots of data, clever assumptions, and time-series modeling, I think it might be possible to reduce the effect of random noise--enough to tempt some over-zealous PR guy to claim detection of 'non-random movements'. Ad copy is cheap, big-data time-series analysis is a little more expensive and less certain.

**P.S.** I'd like if someone could build a full (complete) answer on the subject in such a way I could understand better.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a great deal written on financial models.  At the risk of over simplifying, these sort of things assume that certain patterns (of correlation, or mean reversion,  and such) that have been observed historically will not be too violently contradicted by future patterns absent a change in the underlyings.